# My UI is overlapping in my phone's status bar

Tags: react-native

My problem is in my register page UI. Every time I swipe up my screen because I have a long page, my app logo or image is overlapping in my phone's status bar.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coM8r.png)

This is my UI in my register page.

```
 return(
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>{
      Keyboard.dismiss();
    }}> 
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}}
 >
        <View style={styles.container}> 
          
            <View style={styles.form}> 

            </View>
         </View>

     </ScrollView>

   </TouchableaWithoutFeedback>

)

//my styles
 container: {
      flex:1,
      backgroundColor: '#F8E2CF',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent:'center',
      // paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
      padding:8,
      paddingTop:70,
     //paddingTop:Platform.OS==='android'? StatusBar.height:0
    },


  form:{ 
     alignItems: 'center',
     width:'100%'
```

Comment: Try using `SafeAreaView` (from `react-native`) as a wrapper on the outside?

Comment: hello sir, outside in my  <TouchableaWithoutFeedback>?

Comment: That's right, you may also need to set `flex` to 1

Comment: hello sir, yes I follow your comment, in my posted codes. I wrap it in a safeview and I add style to it, and declare flex:1. But still I got still same problem :(

Answer (score -1):

while I post my problem, I made some research also. And I leave an answer in my post, it might be helpful for those who encounter same problem with mine.
I follow the answer of sir Harrison. And also I follow some video here.
[This is the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wd9Va7pIuPg&ab_channel=LirsTechTips)
I dont know if it's the correct way solution in my problem, however it solve my problem.